# Insert hash to MySQL via pure Ruby, database connection

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm using mysql gem and Ruby 1.9.3, not using Rails. I have the following:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'

# Open DB connection
begin
  con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', '', 'data'

  con.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    shops(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(255),
      latitude DECIMAL(15,10),
      longitude DECIMAL(15,10)
    )")

  ### Loop Starts ### 
    ...

    @place = {"name"=>"Tuba", "latitude"=>13.7383, "longitude"=>100.5883}
    # Write to DB

  ### Loop Ends ###

rescue Mysql::Error => e
  puts e.errno
  puts e.error

ensure
  con.close if con
end
```

**Questions**

1. `@place` is a hash. How can I quickly insert to the `data` table other than iterating it?
2. The loop will continue until the entire process ends. Should I close the connection after each insert, or leave it open until process ends?
3. What if the process terminates unexpectedly? Will it affect the data if connection is not closed properly?

**UPDATE: My first try:**

```
col = @place.map { | key, value | key } # => ["name", "latitude", "longitude"]
result = @place.map { | key, value | value } # => ["Tuba", 13.7383, 100.5883]
con.query("INSERT INTO shops (#{col}) VALUES(#{result});")
```

This, as expected, generates the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '["name", "latitude", "longitude"] at line 1
```

Comment: I have one question, to install MysqlRuby all I need to do is `gem install mysql` right? If anything more need,could you help me?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, are you using pure Ruby or Rails? If pure ruby, yes, you just need to run `gem install mysql`, then add the 2 `require` lines in your Ruby file; if Rails, you put `gem mysql2` in your Gemfile.

Comment: I am using only Ruby..only. I just saw this link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ruby.html ... I am on Ruby2.0-p0,so I don't need `require 'rubygems'`.. :) I think so.. Do I need to install MySQL server seperately ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Of course you need to install MySQL on your computer.

Comment: can you join here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37753/mysql-ruby-installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a method for inserting your data:

```
def insert_place(hash, con)
   statement = "INSERT INTO shops (name, latitude, longitude) VALUES (#{hash['name']}, #{hash['latitude']}, #{hash['longitude']});"
   con.query(statement)
end
```

This method takes your hash and the connection object as parameters. You should reuse your connection whenever possible.

Then in your loop I would use this method like this:

```
@place = {"name"=>"Tuba", "latitude"=>13.7383, "longitude"=>100.5883}
insert_place(@place, con)
```

And lastly to answer your last question... if the program terminates in the middle of your loop, I don't see anything that would "corrupt" your data because its a single query and it will either succeed or fail.. nothing in between. If you want to be able to run your script again in the event of a failure you would need to identify where you left off because running again will cause duplicates.

You could do this manually and curate your data appropriately

OR

you could just add it to your insert_place method so that it will skip the con.query(statement) bit if the entry is already in the database.

Comment: if you are using the raw mysql gem.. yes. its just a wrapper around the mysql c client library. The other option is to use Activerecord. It will abstract all that for you.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you need to extract values from array

```
con.query("INSERT INTO shops (#{*col}) VALUES(#{*result});")
```

Some improvements in code can be done. I hope this will work

```
col = @place.keys # => ["name", "latitude", "longitude"]
result = @place.values # => ["Tuba", 13.7383, 100.5883]
con.query("INSERT INTO shops (#{*col}) VALUES(#{*result});")
# (not tested variant)
con.query("INSERT INTO shops (?) VALUES(?);", col, result)
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO shops (#{*col}) VALUES(#{*result});"` is a syntax error.